# How to extract and save xml payload to file system from apache cxf interceptor

Tags: spring-boot, soap, cxf

I am using Apache CXF LoggingInInterceptor and LoggingOutInterceptor to log XML requests and responses to and from a soap endpoint and I can see the payload in the log but I can't seem to figure out how to extract the XML payloads and save them to file system.

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(servicePortType);
client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

Please suggest any solution or provide me an idea of how do I extract and save the payloads.

Thanks,

Comment: If you just want to log the payloads, Logging{In|Out}Interceptor is easiest way to go.
If you want to do more things on the payloads, you may take a look at the [camel-cxf][1] component, but it could take you some time to familiar with it.


  [1]: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-cxf/src/main/docs/cxf-component.adoc

Comment: @WillemJiang Can you point me to a reference implementation or perhaps a code snippet that utilizes camel-cxf in a similar way as my use case?